# selection of rails -package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed rvm, ruby 1.9.3, rails 4.0 and rails 3.0
The problem is that I have to work with an application using ruby 1.9, and do not know how to select the right package. I would also like to know how to select a particular rails from the command line
One other thing: I can use Rails 4.0 for Ruby 1.9.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't install two Rails versions together, this can lead to various strange behaviours, instead use Gemsets (decribed below).

To install specified Ruby version: `rvm install 1.9.3-p385` - yes, you can even specify pathlevel.

To use that Ruby: `rvm use 1.9.3-p385` - or just `rvm use 1.9.3` if you don't have other 1.9.3 versions.

You should also create Gemset for your app so you won't pollute your rvm's specific ruby install with gems from other projects which you will probably create later.

To do that write `rvm gemset create put_name_here`, you will have now new Gemset in scope of your selected rvm's Ruby install.

To use that Gemset write `rvm gemset use put_name_here`. - You can also do `rvm use 1.9.3@put_name_here` - that will select both Ruby and Gemset with one command.

Now you can do `bundle` and all gems will be installed to specified Gemset under chosen Ruby version.

To make your life easier you can create in root of your app two files containing:

.ruby-version

```
1.9.3-p385
```

.ruby-gemset

```
put_name_here
```

And since then rvm should automatically change Ruby version and select specified Gemset when you will enter that directory.

To list installed Rubies and created Gemsets: `rvm list` and `rvm gemset list` (that shows Gemsets under current Ruby only).

And yes, you can use Rails 4.0 with Ruby 1.9.3

Also, you should check [rvm homepage](http://rvm.io/), everything is well described there.

Comment: Thank you. I think that has solved the problem.
I guess the real problem will come when there's another new version of rails more. I wonder if there will need to uninstall the old rails or doing some kind of actualizacio?
but that's another topic .... Thanks for the reply!